# How to play music from my computer on my stereo

Tags: wireless-networking, music

What are some good ways to play music on my computer through my stereo/receiver in the other room?

I have used the Linksys Music Bridge, but it was unreliable (only connects via wireless when it felt like it), and it does not support Windows 7 which I just installed.

I have a Linksys wireless router.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to get a [**Squeezebox Receiver**](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-930-000041-Squeezebox-Receiver/dp/B0012K87FC) and install [**Squeezebox Server**](http://www.logitechsqueezebox.com/support/download-squeezebox-server.html) on your PC. You can then stream wirelessly around the house. The receiver is usually bundled with a controller as the **Squeezebox Duet**, but if you have an iPod Touch or an iPhone, you can get the [iPeng](http://penguinlovesmusic.de/) app to control it.

This may seem overkill for connection to one stereo. The advantage of the Squeezebox approach is that you can add multiple receivers (other clients, see below), and either stream music to each receiver individually, or synchronise them to get multi-room audio.

There are a few other [Squeezebox products](http://www.logitechsqueezebox.com/product_matrix.html) you might want to consider too.

I have Squeezebox Server running as a service on Ubuntu my Acer Revo and love it, see this [question](http://home4film.com/questions/322/how-do-i-set-up-squeezebox-server-on-ubuntu) on my SE site for more details.

Comment: Seconded - I've got an original SliMP3 and a SqueezeBox 2, and they're both fantastic bits of kit. Sure, there's the need to leave the server running on a PC somewhere, but it sounds like gernblandston is willing to do that anyway.

Comment: +1 for http://home4film.com  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Apple Airport Express does exactly what you want and does it very well.  Other systems are a lot more expensive - from the research I've done.

If you can settle for some wires, then just plug a cable in.

Comment: The Airport Express is nice, but it only streams audio from iTunes.  You can purchase Airfoil to stream audio outside of iTunes.  I'm not sure if there is better way besides that.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be for you to get a long cable and plug your sound output of the pc to the microphone input or other (if your stereo has it) and then just play that way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a more reliable version of the Linksys music bridge so I don't have to screw with cables.

Comment: +1 despite your dislike for cables ... just can't beat the old wired connection :)

Comment: -1. 1) He tagged this question [wireless]. 2) The long cable doesn't scale well, either because of a large house or if he decides to expand to more rooms with speakers.

Comment: please you have to run to the computer for song selection, then run to your player for volume selection. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your stereo and PC supports Bluetooth and you are within range*, this would be the simplest solution.

I've personally use a Creative Xmod Wireless in my current setup as I have the weird requirement of needing it to play simultaneously in two locations.

*range differs for different classes. Class 1 BT devices are about 100 meters, Class 2 10 meters and Class 1 1 meter.